# Django reverse id of choicefield in template

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I need to show the status of a busstop (example data) on a page. I create a class with multiple values here is what is most important of it:

```
class Busstop(models.Model):
    TYPE = (('O', 'Open'), ('C', 'Closed'), ('M', 'Maintenance'))
    stop_status = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=TYPE, default='Open')
```

When I call `{{ busstop.stop_status }}` in my HTML template it only shows the 'O' and not the 'Open' (...). How can I reverse this "ID" to its counterpart and show the 'Open'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `{{ busstop.get_stop_status_display }}`.

In case you need further info about `model_object.get_FOO_display()` method, here is the relevant part of the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. It works for me. :)